# do morphisms of binary operations have to be morphism of units?

Tags: abstract-algebra

? For monoids $(M,b,u)$ and $(M',b',u')$, show by an example that a morphism $f\colon (M,b)\to (M',b')$ of binary operations need not be a morphism of units.

This is a homework problem I got. I think it doesn't make sense, because if $u$ is the unit of the binary operation $b$ on $M$, then by definition of morphism, for all $x$ in $M$, $f(x\,b\,u)=f(x)$ and $f(x\,b\, u)=f(x) \,b'\, f(u)$, so $f(x)=f(x)\, b'\, f(u)$ for all $x$, then by definition of unit, $f(u)$ is the unit of the binary operation $b'$ on $M'$.

So this means that all morphisms of binary operations have to be morphisms of units at the same time. I don't understand why this problem wants me to think of an example that it's not so.

Have I misread this problem, or is it just wrong?

Thanks

By the way, is it OK if I just find an $f(x)$ that's not a surjection, so that $f(x) \,b'\, f(u)=f(x)$ does not work for all the elements in $M'$?

Comment: Consider for instance the map from $(\mathbb{N},\cdot)$ -- i.e., the set of non-negative integers under multiplication -- to itself which sends every $n$ to $0$.

Comment: but does that mean my proof is wrong? can you explain how it is wrong?

Comment: wait....if 0 is not in N, how is f a function from (N, *) to (N, *) then?

Comment: and f has to be a morphism by the way

Comment: $@$Scharfschütze: I said that $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of non-negative integers...so it includes zero.  (Zero is not negative!) And yes, the function I gave you is a (homo)morphism of monoids.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: Oh yeah cos I thought you meant the natural numbers. Thanks

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: but I still don't see how my proof is wrong...can you help me with that?

Comment: Your proof only shows, that $f(u)$ is the unit on the image of $f$ and as $f$ is not necessarily surjective this in general isn't the unit of the whole monoid as the example shows. On the other hand, if $f$ is surjective, then $f$ necessarily maps unit to unit.

Comment: @Aleš Bizjak: thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out, your argument shows that $f(u)$ is a unit of $f(M)$, not that $f(u)$ is a unit of $M'$. The argument suffices for surjective maps, but not for non-surjective maps.

An easy example is to take $f\colon(\mathbb{N},\times,1)\to(\mathbb{N},\times,1)$, with $f(n)=0$ for all $n$ (my naturals have $0$ in them; if yours don't, then just take he nonnegative integers instead.

Another example is to take any monoid with a zero element, say $(\mathbb{Z},\times, 0)$, and consider $M=(\mathbb{Z},\times,1)$ and $M'=(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},\times,(1,1))$, and let $f$ be the inclusion into the first coordinate, $f(n) = (n,0)$.

You can probably now cook up lots of examples along similar lines. All you need is an *idempotent* (an element $e$ such that $e^2=e$) which is not the unit of $M'$.

Comment: So, two [downvotes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67677/using-axiom-of-choice/67680#67680), within a minute of one another, with no explanation on either...